# Procedural Generation Using Classes Pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame

I'm in the process of creating a basic game in pygame at the moment, and one part of that is the procedural generation of new areas as you go off the screen. As a test, I'm looking to generate an object once per area by defining its variables, and then save that area's object within the class for if you come back to it later. Here's what I have at the moment:

```
#area_gen is set to "true" if you move to a new area
#swidth and sheight are set to the size of the screen
#x_area and y_area are defined as you change areas, acting as sector coordinates
#Red is defined in globals

class areas:

    def __init__(self, coords):
        self.coordinates = coords
        self.generated = False

    def gen_objects(self):
        if not self.generated:
            self.objs = []
            obj_type = "test object"
            center_x = random.randrange(105, swidth-25)
            center_y = random.randrange(25, swidth - 175) 
            self.objs.append([obj_type, center_x, center_y])
            self.generated = True

#Within The Game Loop

    if area_gen == "true":
        coords = str(str(x_area) + " " + str(y_area))
        area = areas(coords)

        area.gen_objects()

    for thing in area.objs:
        if thing[0] == "test object":
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, Red, (thing[1], thing[2], 250, 250))

    #Bottom of the Game Loop
    area_gen = "false"
```

What I thought the self.generated variable would do was stop the new object generation if one already existed, but that doesn't seem to be working. The square still generates at a new location even if the area has already been visited. My knowledge on classes is relatively limited, so I'm a bit stuck as to where to go from here.

Comment: why use strings instead of booleans? It may be a part of the problem... (you wrote `area_gen == "true"` instead of `area_gen = True`)

Comment: My computer programming class left True/False and their respective syntax out of the "Boolean" chapter of the curriculum, so I started off by using strings as substitutes. By the time I looked up the proper syntax, I had already started using strings within this program.

Anyway I finally figured out what was going on; turns out my knowledge of how class objects work wasn't exactly accurate. I'll post my fix in a new response.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `area_gen` into the constructor for the areas class, and set `self.generated = area_gen`.  Does this work?  I can't see enough of your code to know, to be honest.

Comment: I apologize, trying to figure out which bit of code is relevant without taking up a few hundred lines is a bit hard in this case. area_gen is set to "true" whenever the area changes (the character goes off screen). What I'm looking for is a way to check if the area specific to the coord variable has been generated before.